# Nagorno-Karabakh

Tags: azerbaijan, disputed-territories, armenia, nagorno-karabakh

I already have my ticket to Armenia and I aim to visit Karabakh. I'm particularly interested in the area below Togh in the South-West which is Azerbaijani land under Armenian control. However, I can find absolutely no information at all about it on the net. Does anybody have any advice/information about this area?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know ? Your question is a little too broad as it is

Comment: I assume you mean the travel basics, how to get there, what prep do you need to do in advance e.g. visas and if accommodation is limited? You have to be explicit on this site, can't rely on common sense unfortunately. P.s. have you seen http://www.lonelyplanet.com/azerbaijan/nagorno-karabakh ?

Comment: I did the entire Janapar trail (from Hadrut to Togh and then further to the north) two months ago. So the answer to your question "Does anybody have any advice/information about this area?" is "Yes, I do.". Unless you specify what kind of advice/information you are looking for that is all I can say.

Comment: If you are visiting Karabakh (as you mentioned, Azerbaijani land under Armenian control) from Armenia without consent of Azerbaijani government, you will be declared [personae non gratae in Azerbaijan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_declared_personae_non_gratae_in_Azerbaijan) and will be denied the entry in case you wish to visit Azerbaijan in the future. Additionally, in case of necessity, appropriate juridical actions based on international laws may be taken against you.